# mySQL query to get results in between a range of months

Tags: mysql

The table structure:

```
+------+-------+--------+--------------------+
| year | month | profit | inventory_turnover |
+------+-------+--------+--------------------+
| 2017 | 7     | 10000  | 2.47               |
| 2017 | 8     | 5000   | 2.47               |
| 2017 | 9     | 10000  | 4.5                |
| 2017 | 10    | 30000  | 6.7                |
| 2017 | 11    | 20000  | 1.7                |
| 2017 | 12    | 15000  | 2.8                |
| 2018 | 01    | 15000  | 1.8                |
+------+-------+--------+--------------------+
```

I want to get the results which are in between 08th month of 2017 and 01st month of 2018.

Current query is :

```
select * from monthly_records where monthly_records.month between 10 and 01 and monthly_records.year between 2017 and 2018 ORDER BY ID;
```

But it returns an empty set.

Comment: Store dates as dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compose a temporary date field called tmp_date using the month and year fields. Then compare that temporary date field with the date range using the between operator. Group By and having clauses needed to be used.

```
select id, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01',',',month,',',year),'%d,%m,%Y') as tmp_date from monthly_records group by id having tmp_date between '2017-12-01' and '2018-01-02';
```

Answer (score 3):

With your current table structure:

```
SELECT *
FROM monthly_records
WHERE (year = 2017 and month >= 8) or (year = 2018 and month <= 1)
ORDER BY ID;
```

I *strongly* recommend not storing the year and month separately.  We got away with a fairly easy query, but things can get out of hand for more complex cases.  Note that when using bona fide dates, we always would have just two date points to check.

Keep it simple and just use date literals here:

```
SELECT *
FROM monthly_records
WHERE date >= '2017-08-01' AND date < '2018-02-01'
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Please refer the current table structure. The year and months are in separate columns.

Comment: i think he has fixed columns for month and year. How you query will compare it with the dates?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's what i am trying to find out. The table structure is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM monthly_records
WHERE month IN (8,9,10,11,12) AND year IN (2017)
ORDER BY ID;

UNION / UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM monthly_records
WHERE month IN (1) AND year IN (2018)
ORDER BY ID;
```

Select UNION/ UNION ALL as per need.

**OR**

without UNION/UNION ALL

```
SELECT * FROM monthly_records WHERE (month >= 8 AND year = 2017) or (month = 1 AND year = 2018) ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: I would replace the `month IN (...)` with `month between 8 an 12`.